# TTY4 exit corrupted text and images

Tags: 20.04, tty

I was playing league through Lutris and furiously pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. It opened the tty4 terminal which I exited with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7/8</kbd> (not sure it lagged a bit).

When I got back to desktop everything looked like this.

However text and images in-app are completely fine (i.e. I'm writing this fine right now)

Should I report this bug somehow? I'm betting it's gonna be fine after reboot, haven't checked yet.

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+ALT+F2 is the graphical session you are trying to get back to.

CTRL+ALT+F1 is the graphical login screen.

The text consoles are among 3-6.

CTRL+ALT+F7 is unstable, on my machine it shows a single blinking cursor only.

This rearrangement of ttys is somewhat new in newer versions.